# Selecting panda dataframe between timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, between

I want to select all rows with timestamps between 12 hours before and 3 hours after a specific timestamp.

My code:

```
yyyy = "2021"
mm = "12"
dd = "01"
mn = "00"
dd = "01"
hh = "00"
akttermin = datetime.datetime(int(yyyy),int(mm),int(dd),int(hh),int(mn),0)
plus3htermin = (akttermin + datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
minus12htermin = (akttermin + datetime.timedelta(hours=-12))
df2 = df.loc[(df['observation-time'] >= minus12htermin) & (dfoutind['observation-time'] <= plus3htermin)]
```

The error message is:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

What could be the error in my code?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `observation-time` column to `datetime`:

```
df['observation-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['observation-time'])
```

Comment: Why you have 2 dataframes: `df` and `dfoutind`?

Comment: Sorry, dfoutind should be df.

Comment: Not a problem. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I already inserted this conversion:                                                                  df['observation-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'). Unfortunately no solution found yet.